# Adding items from one list to another list in another form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form1` which displays a list of students in a `ListBox`.

I use `Form2` to populate this list of students, well I want to.

`Form2` is meant to update the `studentList_Form1` in `Form1` every time a button is clicked in `Form2`.

what I'm trying to figure out is how to actually do this? Because I have tried this

**Form1**:

```
public List<Student> studentList_Form1;

public List<Student> StudentList_Form1
{
    get
    {
        return studentList_Form1;
    }
}
```

**Form2**:

```
public List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

private void update_main_student_list()
{
    using (Form1 newForm = new Form1())
    {
        foreach(Student s in studentList) 
        {
            newForm.StudentList_Form1.Add(s);
        }                
    }
    //As well as the code to populate studentList
}
```

But I keep getting an error saying I need to check if s if null before I use it.

`Student` is a class which is made up of a string name, string address, int id

Comment: your list from form1 will get re=initialized since you are making an instance for Form1 "using (Form1 newForm = new Form1())", you don't have to make an instance

Comment: The `studentList_Form1` is read-only so you cannot call the `.Add()`, the `newForm` and the form that you are currently seeing are two different instance of the same class, I suggest you to use delegate for this type of communications

Comment: @un-lucky - it is a read-only reference, so `.Add()` is fine

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed cannot have an error about `s` being `null`.

The error tells you that `studentList_Form1` in `Form1` is `null`.

But the code is still pointless. You need to use `studentList_Form1` from an existing `Form1` (that list at some point still has to be instantiated) to add items to.

Answer (score 0):

in Form1

you should add **new List < Student >();** when define **studentList_Form1**

```
public List<Student> studentList_Form1 = new List<Student>();

public List<Student> StudentList_Form1
{
    get
    {
       return studentList_Form1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the List studentList_Form1 in Form1 as static instead of creating a new form

```
private static List<Student> studentList_Form1 = new List<Student>();

public static List<Student> StudentList_Form1
{
    get
    {
       return studentList_Form1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Igor can you provide a better solution then?

Comment: The TS has to structure his code so that reference of the list from the first is given to the second.

Comment: @Igor So accessing the object of Form1 in Form2 is a better solution? What about all the other properties of Form1 which can be misused?

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in Form2 and subscribe this event in Form1. update the list in the event handler of Form1.

Answer (score -1):

**Form1:**

```
private List<Student> studentList_Form1=new List<Student>();

        public List<Student> StudentList_Form1
        {
            get
            { return studentList_Form1; }
        }
```

**To Load Form2:**

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
            frm.ShowDialog();
```

**Form2:**

```
    Form1 frm1;    
    public List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

    public Form2(Form1 frm)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                frm1 = frm;

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    studentList.Add(new Student() { studentId = i, studentName = "Student " + i });

            }
```

**to add items to studentList which exists in Form1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var std in studentList)
                frm1.StudentList_Form1.Add(std);
        }
```

Comment: what in case the form2 is not a child of form1?

Comment: then how to access list from Form1 if form1 is not a parent of Form2